# Angular wrap text is not workign with overflow-wrap

Tags: css, angular11

I have the following code and the text is not getting wrapped. i.e 'Action Plan Complete' is the long text and i want to wrap it to similar to 'Action Plan
Complete'.

```
        <td>
            <span class="column-data wrap-text">{{ value }}</span>
        </td>
```

Css:

```
.column-data
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-content: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

td {
    vertical-align: middle;
    .wrap-text {
        max-width:50px;
        overflow-wrap: break-word;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though overflow-wrap and word-break behave similarly there are differences between them. The overflow-wrap property breaks the word if it cannot be placed on the line without overflowing regardless of the language used. The word-break property is used for non-english languages and specifies wraps between letters of languages like Chinese, Japanese, and Korean

use `word-wrap: break-word;` instead of `overflow-wrap: break-word;` maybe it works